# Can I use a rear rotor from another GM vehicle on my 2006 Cadillac dts

Tags: brake-rotor

My rotor is almost completely worn down on the passenger side rear I have a rotor from a Chevrolet that is nearly new can I use it

Comment: what's the rotor from? stack them on top of each other or take measurements if they're exactly the same. sure use it.

Comment: This sounds sketchy...

Comment: Can you add a photo of the old and new one side by side?

Answer (score 1):

If the part has the same dimensions, bolt holes and thickness yes you can use it.

If they are just solid flat cast discs you should be fine. However If it is vented and has significantly less mass or an obviously different pattern i would avoid using it. Different designs will have different performance and behaviour depending upon thier ability to absorb and dissipate heat.

If it is worn it may be worth having it machined to ensure it has a clean flat surface. And i would highly reccomend installing new brake pads.

Personally im in favour of replacing things in pairs. I'd consider machining both sides and replacing both sets of brake pads together.

If the brake rotor is wearing abnormally on one wheel id be keen to try and find out why.

Answer (score 0):

If the part is identical then you should be able to use it, BUT with brakes etc. you should generally replace stuff on a per-axle basis not just one corner, or you can end up with uneven braking which is dangerous.

Ultimately you need to find out why one rotor has worn out or you're just avoiding the real problem.